# Comportamiento extraño en variables de diferentes archivos de React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Creé un componente llamado 'Card', y lo uso en dos archivos, uno llamado Form.js y otro llamado Overview.js y en ambas tengo una variable que se llama cardBody, que funciona como metodo, y lo paso así:

**En Form.js:**

```
 render() {
        // const navigation = this.props.navigation;
        return (
            <Layout style={style.container}>
                <Card body={cardBody()}></Card>
            </Layout>
        )
    }
```

Y mi variable cardBody es así:

```
cardBody = (question = null) => {
    <View>
        <QuestionForm type='text'></QuestionForm>
    </View>
}
```

**En Overview.js**

```
return (
    <Layout style={style.container}>
        <ScrollView>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => { this.navigation.navigate('FormsAnswer') }}>
                <Card header={cardHeader()} body={cardBody('00S##### - ENERGON - IND')}></Card>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </ScrollView>
     </Layout>
)
```

Y mi variable cardBody aquí es:

```
cardBody = (plantName) => (
    <View>
        <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Planta</Text>
        <Text>{plantName}</Text>
    </View>
);
```

El problema es que, según el último archivo que guardé(entre estos dos), es lo que renderiza.

Cabe decir que en la navegación, estos dos archivos son hermanos (forman parte del mismo routeador de react-navigation).

Answer (score 2):

El metodo `cardBody` del componente `Form` no esta retornando nada.
Agrega el `return` que falta:

```
cardBody = (question = null) => {
    return <View>
        <QuestionForm type='text'></QuestionForm>
    </View>
}
```

O usa parentesis como en el componente `Overview`:

```
cardBody = (question = null) => (
    <View>
        <QuestionForm type='text'></QuestionForm>
    </View>
)
```

PD: ¿Podrias explicarnos cual es el proposito de este metodo? ¿Como es utilizado por el componente `Card`?. Probablemente sea mejor usar el props `children` en su lugar